# Show Current Date Facebook Friend Birthdays in List

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

I am writing an app in which i am fetching list of friends those birthdays in next 30 days, and i am able to get that as well, but i am facing a small problem in my list.

Like: I have 4 friends birthdays in next 30 days, so i am getting list of coming facebook friends birthdays but not getting name of friend whom birthday is Today

I guess i am missing something in query.

Code:

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date today = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String today_formatted = formatter.format(today);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);  //set number of days
    String today_plus30_formatted = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday_date != 'null' AND birthday_date > '" + today_formatted + "'AND birthday_date < '" + today_plus30_formatted + "'ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

and if i will use below query, so i am not getting list of my friends:

```
               String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday_date != 'null' AND birthday_date > = '" + today_formatted + "'AND birthday_date < = '" + today_plus30_formatted + "'ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rakesh you did everything and that is correct also:

you just need to delete : "/yyyy"

replace below line, and you done:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure gave permission for accessing friends Birthday date

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
new String[] {"friends_birthday","read_stream", "offline_access"};
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

here is simple example

[How to get FB friends birthday in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231509/how-to-get-fb-friends-birthday-in-android)