# Android facebook contacts birthday details retrieve

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to get facebook contacts birthday details..But unfortunetely i couldn't able to retrieve.It saying to give permission..But i have added permission already in it..

I can able to get my friends name but not birthday date.

how can i get my friends birthday date !

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
new String[] {"friends_birthday","read_stream", "offline_access"};
```

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5350705/1542636)

Comment: post your logcat log so we can see whats the error.Have you added the required permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yeah i added every required permission in manifest.

Comment: paste you logcat log above

Comment: Are you able to see the "friends birthday" in the permissions dialog while login?

Answer (score 0):

Use the OpenGraph API in whatever environment you use to retrieve the information. The birthday is in the user information object, see docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231509/how-to-get-fb-friends-birthday-in-android) too.

Also check your date format is correct is not ?

the correct date format to be used is

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
```

Are you getting null for all birthdays or just some?

Some birthdays will be null, since some FB users have chosen not specify their birthday.

Comment: I tried that already..In opengraph itself when we adding birthday in field..It says "Field is empty or disallowed by access-token"

Comment: see i added one more link