# How to display Facebook events on an android app?

Tags: android, facebook

I am making a calendar application and I want to be able to display the events that are linked to my Facebook account. Now, I know that I need the Facebook SDK for that and I already installed it, but I don't know what the next step is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to access facebook user information after accessing these informations you can easily link them to your calender app

Check these links for taking image of user profile similarly u need to get all details of Users.

[Image of Logged User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841710/get-user-image-from-facebook-graph-api/5841825#5841825)...

[Friends Birthday list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350567/facebook-friends-birthdays-in-android/5350705#5350705)...

Integrating facebook in your Application :

[Github for Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

[Include Graph API for Facebook to access user information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

use graph API and use

```
211600268?fields=id,events,friends.fields(events)
```

the `id used above` should be replaced by your `own facebook id`